# discord.js \n escape character not working in embed using setDescription

Tags: discord, discord.js, escaping

I am trying to create a new line in an embedded message description.

The command is sent using slash commands should it make any difference.

```
/say edit message-id:812711763061375056 description:hello \n newline here
```

[result in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmJvV.png)

The handler looks like this

```
const embedMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(title == undefined ? message.embeds[0].title : title.value)
    .setDescription(description == undefined ? message.embeds[0].description : description.value)
    .setColor(0xfa6607)
```

The type of `description.value` is string

Thanks!

Comment: The character sequence `\n` is not the same as the linefeed character often marked as `\n`. You'll need to parse your input for occurrences of the character sequence `\n` and add in an actual linebreak. Or, assuming your command parser isn't fixed to ignore it, you can just send a message with a linebreak in it (use shift+enter in Discord).

Answer (score 0):

A way around your issue is to have a certain character of your choice represent a carriage return.

This would be done something like this:

```js
//I have chosen "n" as the character
var index = args.indexOf("n"); //looks for n in your message arguments

if (index !== -1) {
    args[index] = "\n"; //replaces any "n" element with "\n"
}

//now you can do whatever you need with your message
message.channel.send(args.join(" "));
```

**Example:** edit message-id:812711763061375056 description:hello n newline here

note: I would highly recommend against eval commands, they are a huge security breach

Answer (score 0):

Today I tested it and it works but not at the start or the end of messages.
But you can also use an invisible final character, like "⠀".
Example.
This:

```
⠀\n\nYour description.\n\n⠀
```

Should give you this:

```
⠀

Your description.

⠀
```

Comment: Just for notice: even if it doesn't show, the code above includes the invisible character and was tested. (The only use of `\n` alone in a an embed text field that I found, was to make the field disappear altogether. In some contexts that can be handy.)